# Is 学长/学兄 gender specific？

Tags: usage, word, gender

So the word 学姐 is gender specific to woman so what about 学长? Is it only use for male? And if so is 学兄 for all gender?

Answer (score 5):

From my experience, 学兄, for male only, is understandable, but is rarely used.

学姐 is used more than 学兄.

学长 is common and gender neutral, although it's more common among men than women.

I also heard of 学弟，学妹.

Comment: 学长 is not gender neutral.

Comment: @zyy I think it's ok to address a girl as 学长, although it's often used among men.

Comment: Well, I would not recommend that use, since I have never heard of it.

Comment: @dan In my university we never use 学兄 actually. Instead, we use 学长 to address a boy from higher grade.

Comment: @TooskyHierot, yeah, I think that's the common sense. But I wouldn't be surprised if someone take a girl as his/her 学长.

Comment: I never use 學長to address a female.

Answer (score 4):

Both 学长 and 学兄 are gender specific and refer to male.

It is however, not common to say 学兄，you would say 师兄。

For a female, you would say 学姐 or 师姐。

Comment: 师兄 is usually used in some scenario like you and certain male are both supervised by the same instructor to conduct academic research while you are a freshman and the male is about to graduate, so I would not recommend to call someone 师兄 if he is merely a 学长 to you.

Comment: @xbh It is a commonly admitted convention, but there are people who do not have a preference.